# how to catch a server response?

Tags: node.js, express, webserver, response

There is a client wich is sending requests to my webserver. This Server should answer with data or an specific code, for example 117 *(yes this a halo reference :D)* Now I need access to the responded data or code. How could I realize this? I found nothing similar here at stackoverflow, may you can help.

Client example:

```
function sendRequest() {
        var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 1309,
            path: '/examplePath?param='+param,
            param: "example"
        };
        http.get(options, function(resp){
            resp.on('data', function(chunk){
                console.log("chunk :",chunk);
            });
        }).on("error", function(err){
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });

}
```

Answering Server:

```
function examplePathFunction(req,res) {

    if(condition) {
        //TODO Server must answer with data
    } else {
        //TODO Server must answer with status 117
    }
}
```

Would : `res.end(date/code);` solve my problem? And how do I catch this response ?

Comment: Did you try `res.render` or `res.send`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
function examplePathFunction(req, res, next) {

if(req.body.data) {
    res.status(200).send({ data: req.body.data });
    return next();
 } else {
    res.status(117);
    return next();
   }
}
```

Though if you're trying to send data through params, look there rather than the request body.

Read more about the Express API: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req